# Как организовать вывод накладной ТОРГ-12 на сайте

Tags: pdf, php, mpdf

Привет!

Появилась необходимость вывода товарной накладной ТОРГ-12. Искал ее в html формате, все безуспешно. Мне объяснили, что все возможные попытки восстановить ее в html оканчивались неудачами. Было принято решение отказаться от этого. Вспомнил, что есть форматы документов типа mpdf, которые на вход принимают данные, вставляют их и выдают документ. Подскажите, пожалуйста, желательно прям с кодом, как реализовать подобное?

Answer (score 1):

На вид, выглядит достаточно просто. Есть **источник данных**: текстовые строки, выпадающие списки, радиобаттоны, которыми заполняются поля (мы их, непосредственно, вбиваем в HTML форму). На сервере генерируем документ по существующему **PDF шаблону**, проблему могут составить только "растущие" записи таблицы. Они не всегда могут уместиться красиво на одной странице.
Из этого финального PDF документа можно получить и картинку и xml-based, и любой другой формат.

Answer (score 0):

А если гененить в pdf и отдавать клиенту? Ну и как-то странно слышать, что тогр-12 не смогли сделать в html

Comment: @cavinc вот это и спрашиваю. Приведите, пожалуйста, пример, как что-то подобное реализовывали

Comment: http://schetov.ru/blanks/torg12/

Comment: @whispeer там нет хтмла, апи для создания тоже

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю генерить pdf с помощью LaTeX. Позволяет описывать размеры ячеек таблиц в миллиметрах, переносы шапок таблиц, нумерация, в общем своеобразный язык программирования, компилятор для документов.
Очень мощный, но требует изучения.